# Pattern to add functions to existing Python classes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, implicit-conversion, implicit, python-class

I'm writing a helper library for *pandas*.

Similarly to scala implicits, I would like to add my custom functions to all the instances of an existing Python class (`pandas.DataFrame` in this case), of which I have no control: I cannot modify it, I cannot extend it and ask users to use my extension instead of the original class.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df.my_function()
```

What's the suggested pattern to achieve this with Python 3.6+?

If exactly this is not achievable, what's the most common, robust, clear and least-surprising pattern used in Python for a similar goal? Can we get anything better by requiring Python 3.7+, 3.8+ or 3.9+?

I know it's possible to patch at runtime single instances or classes to add methods. This is **not** what I would like to do: I would prefer a more elegant and robust solution, applicable to a whole class and not single instances, IDE-friendly so code completion can suggest `my_function`.

My case is specific to `pandas.DataFrame`, so a solution applicable only to this class could be also fine, as long as it uses documented, official APIs of *pandas*.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code I am creating a function with a single `self` argument.
This function is the assigned to an attribute of the `pd.DataFrame` class and if the callable as a method.

```py
import pandas as pd

def my_new_method(self):
    print(type(self))
    print(self)

pd.DataFrame.new_method = my_new_method
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3]})
df.new_method()
```

Comment: I think this matches pretty closely what I mentioned I would prefer not to do. Thank you anyway for the suggestion of how to implement this "runtime patch" of the involved class.